# Sending Custom Packet Structure with data from a file

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I am trying to send a packet with 20 byte checksum, 10 byte sequence and 482 bytes of a file that it reads from. This is what I have below. How do I send the packet with all that info and how does the server know what is what?

```
import socket
import hashlib

buffer_size = 482
port = 5900
file = open('helloworld.txt', 'rb')
transfer = file.read(buffer_size)
hash_object = hashlib.sha1(transfer)
checksum = hash_object.hexdigest()
addr = ('localhost', port)
sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(addr)
print('Connected to', addr)
sock.sendto((checksum + transfer))
file.close()
print("File sent")
sock.close()
sock.send()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a byte-oriented protocol for the TCP data stream.  Your "10-byte sequence" data wasn't demonstrated, so I'll make one up for illustration.  For example:

1. Send the transfer size as a 2-byte big-endian value.
2. Send the 20-byte SHA1 digest of the transfer data.
3. Send the transfer data

Example:

```
import socket
import hashlib
import struct
import os

buffer_size = 482
port = 8000
transfer = os.urandom(buffer_size) # generate some data
hash_object = hashlib.sha1(transfer)
checksum = hash_object.digest() # digest (not hexdigest) is a 20-byte string.
addr = 'localhost', port
sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(addr)
print('Connected to', addr)
sock.sendall(struct.pack('>H',buffer_size) + checksum + transfer)
print("File sent")
sock.close()
```

A receiving server could look like the following.  Note that TCP is a byte streaming protocol, so a blocking `recv(2048)` could return 0 (socket closed) or 1-2048 bytes.  I purposefully picked a small, odd value for receiving to demonstrate that you should buffer reads and extract data according to the protocol.  This example doesn't handle if the data stream ends early.

```
import socket
import struct
import hashlib

class Buffer:

    def __init__(self,sock):
        self.sock = sock
        self.buffer = b''

    def get(self,length):
        # Make sure enough bytes to satisfy the length requested
        # are in the buffer.
        while len(self.buffer) < length:
            data = self.sock.recv(7)
            if not data: break
            self.buffer += data
        # Split off from the current buffer the bytes requested.
        # Keep the remainder for the next request.
        rcv,self.buffer = self.buffer[:length],self.buffer[length:]
        return rcv

s = socket.socket()
s.bind(('',8000))
s.listen(1)
c,a = s.accept()
buf = Buffer(c)
length = struct.unpack('>H',buf.get(2))[0]
chksm = buf.get(20)
transfer = buf.get(length)
verify = hashlib.sha1(transfer)
print(chksm == verify.digest())  # should be "True"
c.close()
s.close()
```